# Write constructor for a library class that doesn't have one

Tags: c++, struct, constructor

I am using a struct from a 3rd party library to pass parameters into library functions.

I wish there were a constructor that would allow me to quickly create a struct, but the library doesn't provide one.

Is there some way to define a constructor outside of the library that I can use within my own code? If not, does anybody else see an elegant solution, here?

My motivation is that I would save some speed because I wouldn't have to construct each struct member twice.

Also, my code would be more readable because I could condense struct creation into one line instead of many lines.

I want to go from this:

```
Point newPoint;
newPoint.x = someXValue;
newPoint.y = someYValue;
```

To this:

```
Point newPoint(someXValue, someYValue);
```

Comment: Ah, I meant in the future! Don't make edits that invalidate answers!

Answer (score 7):

If you're using C++11, you can construct as:

```
Point newPoint {someXValue, someYValue};
```

and if you're not, assuming this is a POD structure, you could:

```
Point newPoint = {someXValue, someYValue};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not using C++11 (limitations of some libraries that I'm using)

Comment: @user2445507 You should probably tag the standard you intend to use if it is not the current one.

Comment: Not a POD. Just an aggregate.

Answer (score 4):

Use a factory method. But you will get another function.

```
Point CreatePoint(int x, int y)
{
    Point temp;
    temp.x=x;temp.y=y;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: added bonus: this will trigger NRVO, so there will be no redundant copying

Comment: I am strongly considering this, but it doesn't solve the efficiency issue (as far as I know). If x and y are some large object instead of an int then they will be constructed in the first line of the function and then again in the second and third.

Comment: c++11 is required to fix that

Comment: @sp2danny: This **might** trigger NRVO. There is no requirement for any given implementation to even provide NRVO. The question is about C++, the language, not a particular compiler, i.e. an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be best in performance perspective or readability, but it is the basic, so I just list it here.

```
class MyPoint : public Point {
public:
    MyPoint(int x, int y) { ... }
};
```

Construct your objects as `MyPoint`, and you can pass it to the library function directly.